# Laravel Passing route to js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a separate js file into laravel public folder, I have decleard my route into web.php, I can use them in blade file but getting error while try to use them in that js file.

```
$.ajax({
   //url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/cats/fetch",
    url:"{{route('cats.fetch')}}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
    success:function(result)
    {
      $('#'+dependent).html(result);
    }

})
```

but when I use hard coded url then its work for instance url:"cats/fetch".
**How can I make it configurable not hard coded into js file**

Answer (score 1):

`url:"{{route('cats.fetch')}}",` is not valid `.js` syntax. You're correct that you can use it in `.blade.php`, but in an external `.js` file, you need to assign it to a variable first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let url = "{{ route('cats.fetch') }}";
</script>
<script src="path/to/file.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Then, in `file.js`, reference the variable:

```
...
url: url,
...
```